# WCF soap service - add http headers

Tags: c#, .net, soap

I and consuming a soap web service using the Service Reference interface in visual studio. The service requires that I include some http headers in the request for authentication.

How can I go about adding http headers to the request is the webrequest exposed at some point in the process?

Comment: Are those custom headers or part of some protocol?

Comment: custom Http header as part of the post request